# Header cell and row cell is not aligned when using display: block in tbody

Tags: html, html-table

I want to align the header and cell value, but couldn't able to do that.

I am using display block for table body scrolling.

I want table data scrolling with the aligned header.

My table data will be dynamic, so couldn't use fixed length for header and cell.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%; padding: 2px;">
  <thead style="display: table-row;">
    <tr>
      <th nowrap="nowrap" align="center">Name</th>
      <th nowrap="nowrap" align="center">Adreess</th>
      <th align="left" nowrap="nowrap" width="100%">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="display: block; width: 100%; max-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: block` overrides the default rendering of the table so you lose the column alignment. There are certain hacks you can use but they have inconsistent results across browsers. There is no good way to achieve what you want without losing semantics or resorting to javascript to size the columns.

My recommendation is to resort to a `position: sticky` header.

```css
thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; padding: 2px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th nowrap="nowrap" align="center">Name</th>
      <th nowrap="nowrap" align="center">Adreess</th>
      <th align="left" nowrap="nowrap" width="100%">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 2px;" align="right">H</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Dhaka</td>
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Bangladesh-South Asia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```